# Key_Down event not firing, How to move camera with keyboard arrows

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

My xaml code  is below;

```
<Page x:Class="Ab3d.PowerToys.Samples.Objects3D.Model3DFactorySample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cameras="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Cameras;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"
    xmlns:ab3d="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Controls;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"  
    xmlns:visuals="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Visuals;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"        
    Title="AllModelsSample"
    MinWidth="600">
    <Page.Resources>
        <DiffuseMaterial x:Key="ObjectsMaterial" Brush="#247589"/>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0 0" EndPoint="0 1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#033C62"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#01131F"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport">
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup x:Name="MainModel3DGroup"/>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <AmbientLight Color="#333333"/>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>

        <cameras:SceneCamera Name="Camera1" Heading="30" Attitude="-10" Bank="0" Distance="10" ShowCameraLight="Always"/>

        <!-- EventsSourceElement is set to MainGrid - this means that the MainGrid's mouse events are subscribed to - this enables camera rotation without the need to be over the rendered 3D element -->
        <ab3d:MouseCameraController Name="MouseCameraController1" UsedMouseButton="Left" EventsSourceElement="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
        <ab3d:CameraControlPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5" Width="150" Height="75"/>
        <Viewport3D x:Name="ViewPort" Margin="0,-10,0,0" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="anakamera" FieldOfView="90" 
                                           Position="0.4,7,7.5" 
                                           LookDirection="0,-0.5,-1"  
                                            />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
        </Viewport3D>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="Silver" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="3D objects created from code with Ab3d.Models.Model3DFactory"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And my xaml.cs code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace Ab3d.PowerToys.Samples.Objects3D
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Model3DFactorySample.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Model3DFactorySample : Page
    {

        public Model3DFactorySample()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CreateModels();
        }

        ContainerUIElement3D barsContainer = new ContainerUIElement3D();
        mamuller mamuller = new mamuller();
        yuzeyler yuzeyler = new yuzeyler();
        public static ModelUIElement3D modelOlustur(
           Double x,
          Double y,
          Double z,
          Double boy,
          Double sag,
          Double sol,
          MeshGeometry3D mesh, Brush brush)
        {
            //Ab3d.Common.EventManager3D
            ModelUIElement3D modelUIElement3D = new ModelUIElement3D()
            {
                Model = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(brush))
            };

            Transform3DGroup transform = new Transform3DGroup();

            //ScaleY is ranged between 0.0 : 1.0, for 0% to 100%
            transform.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform3D(sol, sag, boy));//boyutlar x sol y sag z uzunlk

            transform.Children.Add(
                new TranslateTransform3D(x, y, z));///lokasyonları belırlenıyor x sag sol y asagı yukarı z derınlık
            modelUIElement3D.Transform = transform;
            return modelUIElement3D;

        }
        private void CreateModels()
        {
            Material material;

            material = this.FindResource("ObjectsMaterial") as Material;


            Brush renk = Brushes.Red;
            ModelUIElement3D firin = modelOlustur(8.5, 1.6, -2.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, (MeshGeometry3D)yuzeyler.Resources["fırın"], Brushes.Gray);
            ModelUIElement3D sogutmaplt = modelOlustur(-7.6, 0.4, -2.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, (MeshGeometry3D)yuzeyler.Resources["sogutmaplatformu"], Brushes.Gray);
            ModelUIElement3D bar2 = modelOlustur(1, 2, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, (MeshGeometry3D)mamuller.Resources["12metreKOS-D"], renk);
            ModelUIElement3D bar3 = modelOlustur(1, 2.077, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, (MeshGeometry3D)mamuller.Resources["12metreKOS-D"], Brushes.Yellow);


            barsContainer.Children.Add(firin);
            barsContainer.Children.Add(sogutmaplt);

            barsContainer.Children.Add(bar2);
            barsContainer.Children.Add(bar3);

            //barsContainer.Children.Add(sogutmaplt);
            //ViewPort.Children.Add(barsContainer);
            MainViewport.Children.Add(barsContainer);
            //string yon = "12metreKOS-D";



        }


        #region klavye mouse işlmleri

        private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.N)
            {
                anakamera.Position = new Point3D(0.4, 7, 7.5);
                anakamera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(0, -0.5, -1);
            }

            #region normal kamera ayarları
            if (e.Key == Key.Left)
            {
                RotateTransform3D cameraspin = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 10));
                cameraspin.CenterX = 0;
                cameraspin.CenterY = anakamera.Position.Y;
                cameraspin.CenterZ = 0;
                (anakamera.Transform as MatrixTransform3D).Matrix *= cameraspin.Value;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Right)
            {
                RotateTransform3D cameraspin = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), -10));
                cameraspin.CenterX = 0;

                cameraspin.CenterY = anakamera.Position.Y;

                cameraspin.CenterZ = 0;

                (anakamera.Transform as MatrixTransform3D).Matrix *= cameraspin.Value;

            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                anakamera.Position = new Point3D(anakamera.Position.X, anakamera.Position.Y, anakamera.Position.Z - 0.1D);

            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                anakamera.Position = new Point3D(anakamera.Position.X, anakamera.Position.Y, anakamera.Position.Z + 0.1D);
            }
            #endregion
        }
    }
        #endregion
}
```

I am trying to use the keyboard arrows to move the camera but my Key_Down event isn't firing.
is there anyway i can achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this `ShowMoveButtons="{Binding ElementName=ShowMoveButtonsCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"`. then the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`<Page  ... KeyDown="Window_KeyDown" Focusable="True">`

Then you have to make sure, that your page has the KeyboardFocus.

Comment: Are you sure, that the Page has the keyboard focus? Use Snoop or some other WPF inspector-tool.